# Property is undefined while trying to access property of javascript object

Tags: javascript, object, properties, undefined

I am getting overwhelmed with this issue, can't figure it out.

I am parsing a sample csv with 5 lines (using csv-parser nodejs module), all the first properties of all 4 objects are undefined.

I printed the object (obj instance) here it is:

```
{ 'separator': 'test',
cor: 'Esmeralda',
  tam: [ '40', '40' ],
  brand: 'test2',
  ref: '20441',
  price: '149.00',
  discount: '',
  price_final: '149.00',
  other: '42 e 46 Safira, 38 e 44 agua marina, 36 Quartzo Rosa',
  description: '',
  photo: [ '7894', '7898', '7900', '7823' ] }
```

While doing JSON.stringify on obj here is the result:

```
{"separator":"test","cor":"Esmeralda","tam":["40","40"],"brand":"test2","ref":"20441","price":"149.0
0","discount":"","price_final":"149.00","other":"42 e 46 Safira, 38 e 44 agua marina, 36 Quartzo Rosa","description":"","photo":["7894","7898","7900","7823"]}
```

When I do obj['separator'] or obj.separator I get undefined, what the hell?

Any clues?

EDIT:

Here is the CSV

```
separator;cor;tam;brand;ref;price;discount;price_final;other;description;photo
test;Esmeralda;40 e 40;test2;20441;149,00;;149,00 €;42 e 46 Safira, 38 e 44 agua marina, 36 Quartzo Rosa;;7894, 7898, 7900, 7823
test;Safira ;42 e 46;test2;20441;149,00;;149,00 €;40 Esmeralda, 38 e 44 Água Marinha, 36 Quartzo Rosa;;7908, 7910, 7823
test;Quartzo Rosa;36;test2;20441;149,00;;149,00 €;40 Esmeralda, 42 e 46 Safira, 38 e 44 Água Marinha;;7913, 7901, 7902, 7823,
test;Água Marinha;38 e 44;test2;20441;149,00;;149,00 €;40 Esmeralda, 42 e 46 Safira, 36 Quartzo Rosa;;7907, 7905, 7823,
```

And here is where I read it:

```
const csv = require('csv-parser')
const fs = require('fs')
const results = [];
const resultsByRef = {};

fs.createReadStream('vestidos_sample.csv')
  .pipe(csv({ separator: ';' }))
  .on('data', (data) => results.push(data))
  .on('end', () => {
      uniformData();


      
  });

function uniformData(){
    for(let line of results){
        console.log(line['separator']);   // >> undefined        
    }
}
```

Comment: `JSON.stringify` returns a string, so `obj['separator']` won't work (btw post the code please)

Comment: yes I know that, I just did JSON.stringify to print the actual content of the obj, I am accessing the property using obj['separator']

Comment: Please provide the code of how you create/define/instantiate/get the object and then how are you trying to access it.

Comment: please post the code, you are doing wrong something else

Comment: just attached the code, I am using windows btw if that helps

Comment: Where exactly did you put the `JSON.stringify` that printed this result? Your code does indeed look like it should be working.

Comment: try `.pipe(parse({delimiter: ':'}))`

Comment: parse is not defined @Berto99 on my code.

Comment: @Bergi if I do inside the for loop of uniformData function like this console.log(JSON.stringify(line)) , I see the first property there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed using this csv options:

```
 fs.createReadStream('vestidos_sample.csv')
  .pipe(csv({ skipLines:1,separator: ';', headers: ['separator','cor','tam','brand','ref','price','discount','price_final','other','description','photo'] }))
  .on('data', (data) => results.push(data))
  .on('end', () => {
      uniformData();

  });
```